# How to get the enum object value when passing key using typescript/javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, typescript, object

I have a enum object and how to get the object value when passing the key using typescript

Below switch case works what if the enum object is so long, any other better way to do

```
export enum AllGroup = {
'GROUP_AUS': 'A'
'GROUP_IN': 'B'
}
```

```
var input = 'GROUP_IN'
```

Expected Output

```
B
```

Tried

```
  const renderValue = (input: string): JSX.Element => {
    switch (input) {
      case AllGroup.GROUP_AUS:
        return <>A</>;
      case AllGroup.GROUP_IN:
        return <>B</>;

    }
    return <div></div>;
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want a more formalized approach, you can create a function that returns an object with methods for getting values by keys or returns all values. In the below case `get()` and `getAll()`.

**Refer the below code for reference :**

```js
function createEnum(values) {
  return {
    get: key => values[key],
    getAll: () => values
  };
}

const AllGroup = createEnum({
  GROUP_AUS: 'A',
  GROUP_IN: 'B',
});

   

console.log(AllGroup.get('GROUP_AUS')); // Outputs: A
console.log(AllGroup.get('GROUP_IN'));  // Outputs: B
console.log(AllGroup.get('xyz'));       // Outputs: undefined
console.log(AllGroup.getAll());         // Outputs:{ "GROUP_AUS": "A","GROUP_IN":"B"}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can directly access the enum by the key:

```
enum AllGroup {
  GROUP_AUS = "A",
  GROUP_IN = "B",
}

const renderValue = (input: string) => {
  return AllGroup[input];
};

console.log(renderValue("GROUP_IN")); // Output: B
```

Comment: thanks doesnt work when input is dynamic

Comment: @learntocode2468 I updated the code and it works when I compile and run it. What is the error that you get?

Comment: I have added a code have look